# When to use: class destructor or delete operator

Tags: c++, class, destructor, delete-operator

I was wondering what the difference is between a class destructor and just flat out deleting the class object. To me they look like they do the same thing so how do you chose which one to use?

For example, I'm working on a program where I need to delete some class objects that I created. I have a few class contructors like so `VectorClass *v_temp1 = new VectorClass(v1, size);`and at the end of the function I have them deleted using just the `delete v_temp1` call. It works just fine and the object is being deleted so why would I go through the trouble to create a destructor when I can just simply do that?

Comment: delete will also deallocate the memory.

Comment: Destructors don't free that object's memory. They just destroy the object. You shouldn't normally need a destructor if you utilize RAII. And even easier than your example is `VectorClass v_temp1(v1, size);`, which you don't need to clean up after.

Comment: The `delete` operator is used to destruct dynamically allocated instances obtained with `new()`. The destructor of a class should never be called directly.

Comment: Ahh ok that makes sense. Thanks you guys, I wish I could click the answer check on a comment haha!

Comment: You don't choose. If you new it, you have to delete it. If VectorClass contains some things which are new'd, and you don't delete them in its destructor (or elsewhere), you leak memory, even if you delete the VectorClass.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, Never say never. It's important when using placement new.

Comment: @chris Though you're right, I don't really think this is in question here ;) ... (I've been missing a _'usually should never ...'_)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A class's destructor is responsible for cleaning up any resources it might have allocated.

The `delete` operator is responsible for destroying dynamically allocated objects. That is, you should `delete` anything that you create with `new`. The process of destroying an object of class type will first call its destructor and then deallocate the object.

So the destructor will be called whenever a class type object is destroyed. An object might be destroyed in various ways, one of which is using `delete`.

We prefer automatic allocation, because it is much safer than dynamic allocation. An automatically allocated object is destroyed automatically when it goes out of scope (which will call its destructor, of course). In your case, I would instead write:

```
VectorClass v_temp1(v1, size);
```

This object does not need to be `delete`d, but it certainly will be destroyed and its destructor will be called.

Answer (score 2):

Class destructor is called automatically whenever an object ceases to exist. So you cannot 'choose if to use it or not` - destructor call is built in the language. (Technically you can and sometimes you need to call destructor manually, but not in normal cases). You do not need to provide a destructor - but if you want to execute some code when objects of your class get destroyed destructor is the right place.

Operator `delete` needs to be manually used whenever you no longer need an object which was created with `new` operator. Operator `delete` calls destructor and then frees memory allocated by `new`.

If in C++ - like e.g. in Java - `new` were the only way to create objects that the distinction between `delete` and destructor would be technical. But in C++ you can create objects in other ways, the most important is - on the stack. And creating objects on the stack is recommended way. In your example

```
VectorClass *v_temp1 = new VectorClass(v1, size);
```

you are not using recommended way. You should use

```
VectorClass v_temp1(v1, size);
```

Then destructor will be automatically called at the end of the block, and there is no need (or even possibility) to use `delete`.

Comment: I see, I came from java so it was just convention for me to use 'new' when creating objects. The thoroughness to your answer was very helpful!